# could not save changes in jsp pages

Tags: jsp, aem

When I create a jsp page in folder and I click *Save All* in CRXDE  it gives me this error

> Could not save changes. Received 409 (Conflict) for saving changes in workspace crx.default.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: Of what type are the node you are creating and the parent?

Answer (score 4):

This is a common issue wih CRXDE Lite.  You can sometimes recover from it, but usually the best you can do is to close your browser and start over.

One thing to check: make sure that you are signed on as a user with sufficient rights to apply your changes.

**Update**

How to avoid the issue in the first place?  Form the habit of clicking Save All after every change you make, including adding properties and deleting or renaming nodes.

Comment: It didn't help...turning on/off instance too didn't help..any other ideas?